# Auto-sync Visual Studio's Class View

Tags: visual-studio, ide, vs-classview

Is it possible to have Visual Studio's Class View pane (available under View > Class View) automatically synchronize to current symbol? Basically execute View.SynchronizeClassView whenever the current symbol changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546113/visual-studio-automatically-refresh-class-view-when-changing-class/734204#734204) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546113/visual-studio-automatically-refresh-class-view-when-changing-class/1003074#1003074).  I find your phrasing more along the lines of what I would have asked.  Not sure why you didn't get any answers.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, an automatic synchronize (without hotkey) will not be implemented.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/15963322-sync-class-view-with-code

> I want to personally thank you for taking the time to share this
>   suggestion. Since the suggestion you raised has not gathered many
>   votes, the Visual Studio IDE team is prioritizing other suggestions
>   and closing it at this time.
>
> If you would like us to reconsider this, please create a new
>   suggestion. Again, thank you for sharing with us!

Comment: To make the treatment of user requests even more clear, they decided that website costed them too much money and took action to shut it down. To be honest, it's even more confusing for me as I have no idea whether uservoice.com was/is affiliated with MS or not.