# Visual Studio - Automatically refresh class view when changing class

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, eclipse, ide

I come from a Java background and have spent many years using Eclipse. One feature that I miss when using Visual Studio (2008) is that the class view does not automatically refresh when I change class. In Eclipse it has a (class) 'Outline' window which represents the current class and shows methods/properties etc, this always updates to the class one is using.

The equivalent 'Class View' in VS does not automatically refresh according to the current class I am visiting. I wondered if anyone knew a way to make this happen?

Ideally I'd like the VS view to be as similar to Eclipse as I could get it, but this one feature would be great.

Thanks in advance,
Will

Comment: Eclipse is not alone, Netbeans does the same.

Comment: old question, but important!  The  proposal to bind to a key using Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and see if you can find "View.SynchronizeClassView". is useful however,  it is broken in many versions of Visual Studio including VS 2019 16.4.3.  As a workaround if you are using Resharper (and most people do)  you can use the file structure window which autosyncs and pretty much provides the same info if you have 1 file per class.

Answer (score 50):

After reading kingmaxxx's reply, I went to Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and bound Ctrl+Shift+C to View.SynchronizeClassView in Text Editor view.  This seems to supplant and supplement the original behavior (View.ClassView), as it will display ClassView if it wasn't visible and focus on the current class.

(Visual Studio 2008)

Comment: Broken in VS2012 for MFC Projects - Not to be fixed https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780808/synchronize-classview-does-not-work-in-c-mfc-projects

Comment: In VS2013 what I get is that what is selected is the project, not the class.

Comment: All I get in VS2013 is the 'Class View' focused or opened.

Comment: Is there a GUI button to do this, that one can toggle on?  A keyboard shortcut is not an optimal solution for me.

Comment: @Avi - an additional click is required to scope the class view to a specific member - click on the name of any class, property or method in the Text Editor view before synchronizing.  The Class View will then highlight the correct member.

Comment: I was using this alot , but it is broken again in VS 2019 16.4.3

Comment: This seems to be the correct answer... But it's not working on VS 2019 16.4.5 too... I'll give it a try to Codemaid.

Comment: This seems to working in 16.7.6 for C++ projects. Note, it must be executed from a Text Editor window, so you may chose to limit the keyboard shortcut to the "Text Editor" context, or else you may get "'View.SynchronizeClassView' is not available."

Answer (score 21):

**For Visual Studio 2005**

I found a solution that does not update the view automatically, but at least you get a context entry that helps:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ansonh/archive/2005/12/09/502020.aspx

You can also define a shortcut key:

Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard and see if you can find "View.SynchronizeClassView".

---

Oh, just for laughs - here is the answer of Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dae8h2s.aspx

> ...you can select any symbol in the Code Editor and
>   locate it **instantly**...

After **7 Steps**...

> "Class View **automatically** scrolls
>   to the location of the selected symbol
>   in its hierarchy. "

Comment: For clarification, the View.SynchronizeClassView keyboard shortcut DOES work with VS2010 RC.

Comment: The Microsoft doc really is (presumably unintentionally) funny. How they consider such a slow and manual process to be 'instant and automatic' beggers belief.

Comment: Sam, I agree. Synchronizing Class View is a natural need. If they would really use their own compilers and tools (which they don't) such questions wouldn't have to be asked. And the documentation would be better.

Comment: I was using this alot , but it is broken again in VS 2019 16.4.3

Answer (score 14):

The best way is to create a context menu when you right-click on a type in code editor.
Tools->Customize
Click on 'Commands' tab. Select Context Menu radio button, and select "Editor Context Menus | Code Window".
Then "Add Command" and select View->Synchronize Class View.

Now whenever you right-click on a type, you can select "Synchronize Class View". It's the very top context-menu item.
Looks like this:
[image: Context-menu]

Answer (score 10):

I can't help you with the class view, but maybe you want to give the solution explorer a try? You can synchronize this one via:

```
tools -> options -> projects and solutions -> general
enable "track active item in solution explorer"
```

Comment: This is what I used! The class view synchronise keyboard shortcut would not work with various bindings.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with View.SynchronizeClassView is that is doesn't work when a class is being viewed from a virtual folder.

Answer (score 2):

based on kingmaxxx's response I found that you can add a button to your toolbar to do the same:

Tools|Customize -> Commands[tab] -> View[Categories]

Grab the Synchronize Class View button and drag it to one of your toolbars.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had time to get this to work yet, but there is code for a VS2003/2005 add-in to auto-sync [here](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.vstudio.extensibility&tid=2a8a5328-d12c-434e-a58d-0bfb400772cf&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=en-us&p=1) (see the post marked "answer").

Incidentally, this question seems to be a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449302).

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017, CodeMaid Spade comes to the rescue quite perfectly.

[Codemaid VS Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid)

At first, I couldn't find the equivalent to 'Class View'.  It's called Spade.

It auto-syncs to the currently open class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any ways to do this but I agree that it would be a nice feature.

You can track items in Solution Explorer though (Options->Project and Solutions->General->Track Active Item in Solution Explorer).

Answer (score 0):

Also coming from java (Eclipse), I missed the outline (Class viewer). I have tried many solutions and the best I found is to use the [CODEMAID extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SteveCadwallader.CodeMaid).

It also provides a lot of other tool but you are free not to use it!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this small CodeNav extension does this work too:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamirBoulema.CodeNav

Yes, "Codemaid -> Spade" looks greater, but it's not just viewer - it has IMHO rather dangerous code drag feature, which could not be disabled unfortunatelly.

P.S. I wonder MS staff themselves doesn't need this feature?!

Answer (score -2):

Coming from Eclipse you will miss a lot of such features. What I miss most for navigation is an easy *go to type*, *go to inheritor* and so forth.  Other features, such as nUnit support are not part of the vanilla Visual Studio, too. Here is a list of Add-Ins that bridge the gap:

- [CodeRush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/)
- [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)
- [TestDriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/), just nUnit integration

But here comes the drawback: They all charge you money (TestDriven.net only for commercial use). However, they all offer free trials.

Comment: IIRC you can /go to type/ with shift-F12.

Comment: Ctrl+F12, Shift+F12, or make your custom shortcuts

Answer (score -3):

Tools Menu -> Options

Then, in the "Project And Solutions" area, you can select to track the active item.

Comment: Verified on Visual Studio 2008 (w/ Resharper 4.1)

Comment: This works for Solution Explorer, but not Class View, which is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score -5):

With Resharper, ALT+SHIFT+L goes to the current file in Solution Explorer.

Comment: It works only for Resharper so I don't consider this to be an answer although it works with my visual studio + resharper 4.1